# What is the meaning of 庸 in the phrase 毋庸置疑?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, chengyu, literary-chinese

毋庸置疑 is a chengyu. Its meaning is "beyound any doubt", but what is its verbatim meaning in literary Chinese?

- 毋 is like "don't"
- 置 is "to place, to put"
- 疑 is "doubt"
- 庸 I am not sure of the correct meaning for

Please, if possible, explain the grammatical structure of the sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[庸](http://www.zdic.net/z/19/xs/5EB8.htm) means `需要` (need) here.

> (1) (会意。小篆字形。从用,从庚。“庚更”同音,表更换。先做某事,然后更换做别的事。本义:用;需要)
>
> (2) 同本义 [need;adopt]
>
> (4) 常与否定副词“无”、“勿”、“弗”连用
>
> (5) 又如:无庸讳言;无庸细述;毋庸讳言;

So `毋庸` means `无须/不必` (no need to).

Answer (score 0):

a doubt is not needed
here庸 some parts like need or necessary

Comment: I got a notice saying "We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed."

so, is the answer judged only by the number of words? is a long trash more valuable than one keyword?

The answer to this question only needs a line of words for the meaning of one single character. That's all, even in dictionary it is in this way

Answer (score 0):

80% of the time 庸 means `mediocre;commonplace`,15% of the time 庸 means `need;adopt`.

---

1.平常，不高明的：平庸。庸医。庸言。庸俗。庸人。昏庸。庸主（平庸或昏庸的君主）。庸夫。庸暗（平凡，愚昧）。庸庸碌碌（没有志气，没有作为）。

2.需要：毋庸置疑。无庸细述。无庸讳言。南海自古以来就是中国的领土，这是毋庸置疑的!

3.You can click [here](http://dict.baidu.com/s?wd=%E5%BA%B8&tupu=01) for more details about 庸!